# Tags for buffer/file/dir local variables

Tags: discussion, tags

One question I saw today had the following four tags attached to it : [file-local-variables](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-local-variables), [local-variables](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/local-variables), [buffer-local](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buffer-local), [directory-local-variables](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/directory-local-variables). It seemed a bit overkill to me, but I don't know what the best set of tags would be.

AFAIK these are the different types of "local variables" :

- Buffer local variables can have a different value in each buffer. See [`(info "(elisp) Buffer-Local Variables")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer_002dLocal-Variables.html#Buffer_002dLocal-Variables).
- File local variables are defined per file. They are a way to give a buffer-local value automatically when visiting a file. See [`(info "(elisp) File Local Variables")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Local-Variables.html#File-Local-Variables).
- Directory local variables are defined in a file named `.dir-locals.el` of a given directory, and behave similarly to file local variables, except they are used for every file of every (sub)directory of the given directory. See [`(info "(elisp) Directory Local Variables")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Directory-Local-Variables.html#Directory-Local-Variables).
- Terminal local variables can have a different value for each terminal. I'm not if they can be defined from lisp. See [`(info "(elisp) Multiple Terminals")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Multiple-Terminals.html#Multiple-Terminals).
- Frame local variables are an obsolete functionality. See docstring of `make-variable-frame-local`.
- "Local variables" is the name used in the manual for let-bound variables. 
  See [`(info "(elisp) Local Variables")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Local-Variables.html#Local-Variables).

Currently the tag [local-variables](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/local-variables) is a mix of all of them. What's the correct set of tags to use to cover the above list ?

Comment: I'm generally a partisan of following the section headings in the Emacs documentation for tags, which saves us from inventing a new taxonomy and makes our taxonomy automatically consistent with official Emacs resources. On this basis, those tags are fine, except that we might rename [tag:buffer-local] to [tag:buffer-local-variables]. But if [tag:local-variables] is getting misused, maybe we should rename it.

Comment: Note: if the conclusion of this discussion is that a tag needs to be renamed, please don't do it manually: moderators have a tool to do this without bumping questions.

Comment: @Gilles: +1 for using Emacs terminology. Sometimes it is arcane, however, so (1) the tag description should mention more common terms for the same thing and (2) in some cases we should perhaps use the more common term. What to use for yanking, for example? `yank`? `paste`? In general, though, I think we should stick with Emacs jargon. In the long run, it helps users more (e.g. to find more info).

Comment: @Drew For such cases we can use tag synonyms. Speaking of which, this area space needs to be reviewed — [I've asked a new question](http://meta.emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/446/should-we-kill-or-yank-some-copy-paste-tags), because our discussion two years ago was inconclusive and we now have the benefit of experience from semi-unregulated use.